# Three.js, добавление объекта в сцену

Tags: javascript, three.js, position

Пытаюсь реализовать подобное

http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_voxelpainter
но с шестигранниками. Сам шестигранник создаю так:

```
hexGeo = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 50, 50, 50,6);
```

Не могу разобраться, что делать с координатами создаваемых объектов, чтобы они не наезжали друг на друга, не было пробелов и тому подобного. Как я понимаю, нужно редактировать вот эту строку, но не знаю, что здесь поменять, или через эти методы положение объекта можно описать только для куба?

```
voxel.position.divideScalar(50).floor().multiplyScalar(50).addScalar(25);
    scene.add( voxel );
```

Comment: Сетка из шестиугольников не такая простая, по сравнению с обычной "квадратной". Может быть этот ресурс поможет - http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/